# simply I want to make target when build is fail of maven project

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

I want to make a target when already remaining my build is staying failed  also this can be done using surefire plugin as below

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

but the problem is it also makes build the success of a project and can not get details when integration tests fail I want a make target with remaining project status to build failed. 
can we do that?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to make a jar in target folder irrespective whether your test cases passed or failed?

Comment: exactly that is what I want but also remain project build status failed

Answer (score 0):

For integration tests, you should use the Maven Failsafe Plugin. It runs after the jar in target is created, so in case of failure that jar would exist.